# Enemies Projectiles Wont Append?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make my enemy shoot my player but for some reason the bullets arent showing nor they are shooting at the player I don't even know why, I even draw the bullets on my window

```
bulls = []
runninggame = True
while runninggame:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            runninggame = False

    for bull in bulls:
        if bull.x < 500 and bull.x > 0:
            bull.x += bull.vel  # Moves the bullet by its vel
        else:
            for enemys in enemying:
                if playerman.x - 100 <= enemys.x <= playerman.x + 100 and playerman.y - 100 <= enemys.y <= playerman.y + 100:
                    bulls.pop(bulls.index(bull))
                    bulls.append(enemybullets(round(enemys.x+enemys.width//2), round(enemys.y + enemys.height//2), 6, (0,0,0), facing))
```

then I called it below

```
    for bull in bulls:
        bull.draw(window)
```

my enemy projectile class

```
# enemys bullets
class enemybullets(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,radius,color,facing):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.facing = facing
        self.vel = 8 * facing

    def draw(self,win):
        pygame.draw.circle(win, self.color, (self.x,self.y), self.radius)
```

Comment: Please simplify your code first. There seems to be a lot of non-relevant code to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not ever moving or drawing the bullets.

Another loop over the `bull` list would do it.  Your code does not include anything about drawing the window, so I've had to make assumptions.

```
while runninggame:
    [...]

    for enemys in enemying:
        playerman = math.sqrt(enemys.x**2 + enemys.y**2)
        if distance  >= 250:
            new_bullets = enemybullets(playerman.rect.x, playerman.rect.x, enemys.x/distance, enemys.y/distance, (0,0,0))
            bull.append(new_bullets)

     # Re-paint the screen
     [...]

     # Move and Paint the enemy bullets
     for b in bull:
         b.move()
         b.draw( window )
```